# Redirect URL with Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, redirect

I have a full working site built with Drupal 8. I already managed to use Apache in order to redirect some pages from an old domain to the new one, but now I have to set up a rule to redirect the same page from two URLs. Basically I would like to redirect from https://example.com/course/name-course=?True to 
https://example.com/course/name-course.

I already tried to use the RedirectMatch as

```
RedirectMatch 301 "/(.*)/(.*)?=True" "https://example.com/$1/$2"
```

But I can't get where I want.